# PHP curl works on localhost but not on the web server?

Tags: php, rest, curl

The below php code is making a REST API call that returns json object. This works fine when i use it on my localhost using WAMP Absolutely no problem.

However when i push this app on the server it would TimeOut and display 503 Service Unavailable.
I checked the logs it has an entry :

> The TimeOut Specified has expired.

I contacted my admin he just said this app listens to PORT=64665 and HOST=0.0.0.0. What does that mean? What more changes do i need to make in my code to make it work on the server ? Help

```
<?php
$url = "http://xyz.net/v2/plan/";   // I have changed the REST URI API Link for security reasons 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump json
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

$response = "http://xyz.net/v2/plan/";
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the port to what he said? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 64665 );`

Comment: and have you checked that the server you are using resolves xyz.net to the correct ip address?

Comment: @scragar I tried setting curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 64665 ); but it would still not work

Answer (score 0):

Check your server's /etc/hosts file, there could be the problem, ie. domain mapped to another (wrong) IP address.